# How can I add tabBarOption to the code bellow? so that I can use tintColor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile, error-handling

How can I add tab Bar Option to the code bellow and use tint Color as well.
I want to use active and inactive for the icon inside the tab Bar Option

```
import React from 'react'
import { SafeAreaView, Text } from 'react-native';
export default class Chat extends React.Component {
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    let tabBarIcon = () => {
        return <MaterialIcons
            style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}
            name={'chat'}
            color={'#000'}
            size={30}
        />
    }
    return { tabBarIcon }
}
render(){
    return(
        <SafeAreaView>
            <Text>Chat</Text>
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

As described in official [site](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-based-navigation.html) . tabBarIcon is a function that is given the focused state, tintColor, and horizontal param, which is a boolean.

**Try this**

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    let tabBarIcon = ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor }) => {
        return <MaterialIcons
            style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}
            name={'chat'}
            color={tintColor}
            size={30}
        />
    }
    return { tabBarIcon }
}
```